# How can I retrieve the location of a PanGesture event in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and trying to implement a PanGesture for an Image element. I want to get the current position (X, Y) of the pan gesture when it occurs. I have been using the PanUpdated event, but I'm unsure how to correctly extract the location information from the event args (e). Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to obtain the X and Y coordinates of the gesture?

Code snippet:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            canvasView.PaintSurface += pictureboxpaint;
            var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
            panGesture.PanUpdated += mousemove;
            picturebox.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
        }
        private void mousemove(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.X` == `e.TotalX`

`e.Y` == `e.TotalY`